# How to loop my data for PHP

Tags: php

I have some data which was json decoded and looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [13] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [buildingId] => 1
                )

        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [20] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 1
                )

        )
```

Thing is i don't know how to loop to get the information to use it in my script.

I need to get for example:

```
$key, $innerkey, $Id = 1
Object [8][20].Id = 1
```

The two numbers are X;Y co ordinates so its important i get those values aswell as the id.

I managed to get the first key:

```
$obj = JSON_decode($_GET['data']);  
    foreach($obj as $key) { 
        echo $key;                      
    }
```

How do i get the innerkey assigned to a variable ?

Comment: Try http://array.include-once.org/ for some syntax help. And use the second parameter of json_decode to get a plain array possibly.

Comment: You need a nested loop.....for traversing nested objects.

Comment: Please see edit at bottom for error i get when attempting to get values inside `$key`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `json_decode($_GET['data']);` to `json_decode($_GET['data'], true);`

If the second parameter is `true` then it return the array else it is object.

```
$obj = json_decode($_GET['data'], true);  
    foreach($obj as $key=>$val) { 
        foreach($val as $k=>$v){
           echo $k." : ".$v['Id'];
           echo "<br>";
        }                      
    }
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: How am i going to get the values inside $key if i don't know the the pointer number  ?

Comment: you could alter the code to be foreach($obj as $key => $subArray). Then you can do another foreach (or other traversal method) on the $subArray. $Key in this case would then be [6] and [8].

Comment: @Dave : edited the answer, It will work only if your array structure wont change.

Comment: ok so how do i get the value of `id` from $v at the end? i tried `$v->id `

Comment: `$k` wiibe `id` and `$v` will be `1`, execute the code and try

Comment: im not getting output for `echo $v;` its blank

Comment: OR try this : echo $k." : ".$v['id'];

Comment: No i get `6:13:Array` for `echo $key.":".$k.":".$v;`

Comment: `$v['id']` also didn't output any thing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap numeric keys with {}. Kind of a PHP caveat.

`echo $obj->{8}->{20}->Id;`

Comment: If i dont know the values but need to assign them to variables... i can't work out how to get "20" to a variable i got the other two assigned as Dasun explained.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two foreach loops for this as below

```
$obj = JSON_decode($_GET['data']);  
    foreach($obj as $key) { 
        foreach($key as $val) { 
          echo $val->id;                      
        }                    
    }
```

## updated answer

```
$obj->{8}->{20}->Id = 10; // assigned the value for testing purpose. 

$a = 8;
$b = 20;

echo $obj->$a->$b->Id;
```

Comment: I tried this but i get `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` for `echo $val`

Comment: can you please print_r($val) and post the output here

Comment: `stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
)
stdClass Object
(
    [Id] => 1
)`

Comment: How do i get the value `[13]` for example see the first data object in question i have `[6][13].id` I got `6` stored in `$key` but not `13`

Comment: if I understand question right above will iterate in the each object and get the value.

Comment: i should be able to for example do : `echo $key = 6, echo $sumin = 13, echo $val->id = 1` but i can't get the 13

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
$array = (array)json_decode($_GET['data']);  
foreach ($array as $key) { 
    var_dump($key);
}
```

or

```
$array = json_decode($_GET['data'], true);  
foreach ($array as $key) { 
    var_dump($key);
}
```

json_decode()'s 2. parameter: true: to array, false: to object.